# Is it possible to say Ändern des Namens?

Tags: translation

I am proofreading a translation by someone who is a native German speaker, but who moved away from Germany at a young age. They have translated the phrase "Modify name" as "Ändern des Namens", which I don't believe is a possible way of saying this. To me, it seems that the phrase is simply incorrectly constructed.

The context is passengers who have incorrectly filled out their details for a ticket; the immediate context is: "Then click on 'Modify name'". There are obviously a number of ways of translating this phrase. The question is simply whether it is actually possible to say "Klicken Sie dann auf 'Ändern des Namens'".

Comment: Sure, though, depending on the context, we more likely would need a definite article for the noun "Ändern". An alternative would be "Namensänderung". Both are used for instance when a couple marries and they agree on one common name. In your case, the idea is "to edit the field of the form which contains the name", and not "to change the name in the passport". In this case I would simply write "Namen ändern" or more clearly "den Namen des Reisenden ändern".

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by the question. What is to be translated sounds a bit like a help text. Of course that text should then use what the button actually says. Is there already a translation of the page with that button into German? What does it say? Or is this about how to translate the page? Or is all of this purely hypothetical?

Answer (score 16):

As a construction, the phrase "Ändern des Namens" is correct. The German infinitive can be used as a verbal noun, and in this case, it can be accompanied by a noun in genitive that would be the (usually accusative) object in other constructions.

However, "Andern des Namens" translates to "Change of name" or "Modification of name" and thus is not a very accurate translation of "Modify name". A translation closer to the original would be "Namen ändern". In that phrase, the infinitive *ändern* is not a verbal noun, and therefore written in lowercase.

Comment: I stand corrected. I am familiar with an infinitive being used as a verbal noun, but I have not seen it without a definite article, which is why I had serious doubts.

Answer (score 7):

The phrase is correct in some contexts, and is possibly correct in the given context (it's not clear form the limited informastion). But I would suspect that "Namen ändern" would be more appropriate and shorter, or possibly "Namensänderung".

Answer (score 6):

"Ändern des Namens" is an absolutely correct phrase and can be used in the context given in your question. Anyway, imo the point is not to find the most accurate translation, but to find the most suitable German phrase for the given purpose.

As you write

> The context is passengers who have incorrectly filled out their details for a ticket.

Therefore passengers are requested to correct the mistake and I suggest

- Namen korrigieren

or

- Namenskorrektur

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with *Ändern des Namens*, since the infinitive is typically used in dialogues as in *Datei speichern*. You may prefer *Namen ändern* for the sake of brevity, however.

Answer (score 3):

All previous answers recommend *»**Namen** ändern/korrigieren«*. I wouldn't do that since *»Namen«* is ambiguous (singular/plural). Better:

> **Name** ändern

Comment: Aber *Name* soll hier doch im Akkusativ stehen d.h. es soll *Namen* sein. Es scheint mir also, dass Ihr Vorschlag ungrammatikalisch ist.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: In der Frage heißt es _»Then click on 'Modify name'«_. Ich nehme an, es geht um einen Button und da halte ich »Name ändern« für die beste Lösung. Die Optionen »Ändern des Namens« und »Den Namen ändern« sind zwar auch möglich, aber nicht üblich, weil umständlich und raumgreifend. »Name ändern« ist nicht ungrammatisch.

Comment: Ich habe die deutsche Grammatik aus [Duden](https://www.duden.de/deklination/substantive/Name_Ruf_Benennung_Bezeichnung) und vielen anderen Lehrbüchern und [Sites](https://www.crodict.de/nomen/deutsch/Name), https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/substantive/Name.htm usw. gelernt, und nicht aus Buttons. Kennen Sie ein einziges Lehrbuch das *Namen* als Akkusativ von *Name* angibt?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ausdrücke wie _Name ändern_ nennen sich Telegrammstil, das ist erlaubt.

Comment: "Erlaubt"?? Ja, es ist "erlaubt" ungrammatisch zu schreiben. Ich denke, dass unsere jeweiligen Gesichtspunkte klar sind.    Weitere Diskussion scheint mir jetzt zwecklos.

Answer (score 0):

Wer schreibt "Name ändern" meint vermutlich dies als Kűrzel fűr "Den Namen ändern" durch Auslassung des Adjektives, sieht aber dann
dass "Namen ändern" auch als Plural gedeutet werden kann "die Namen ändern" und verkűrzt deshalbe "Namen" zu "Name". Das ist ein bei
buttons durchaus űblicher Versuch trotz Platzsparen klar zu bleiben; als Programmierer hat mit damit eben zu kämpfen und wählt weder gender-sternchen noch korrekte Gramatik.